# Getting around "Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute" with async - i.e. without locking

Tags: c#, asynchronous

I have a UI displaying some graphs that are held in an observable collection. The user can change the time span that the graphs are all referencing to - there's a listener that then triggers it to loop through them and re-fetches the data, which can take a while.

```
foreach (TimeSeriesDataViewModel viewModels in Trends)
{
    viewModels.TimeSeriesDataModel = await modelProvider.GetTimeSeriesDataFor(viewModels.KPIViewModel.KPIModel,
                                                                                TimeSpanViewModel.StartTime,
                                                                                TimeSpanViewModel.EndTime);
}
```

My problem is, while this is happening the user can modify the collection by adding more trends, or deleting them. This results in the "Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute" exception.

Normally, I'd be doing this using a background process, and I'd put a lock around accessing the collection. However, locks don't work with asynchronous code (which I'm new to!). Is there a standard way of doing something like this?

I'm using thread safe concurrent observable collections from [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/208361/Concurrent-Observable-Collection-Dictionary-and-So).

**Edit:**

After some experimentation, this seems to work well. However, I'm lucky that I don't need await removing items, so I can keep the await always outside the await lock statements.

```
        ConcurrentDictionary<ITimeSeriesDataViewModel,Task<ITimeSeriesDataModel>> updateDataTasks = new ConcurrentDictionary<ITimeSeriesDataViewModel,Task<ITimeSeriesDataModel>>();
        lock (Trends)
        {
            foreach (ITimeSeriesDataViewModel viewModels in Trends)
            {
                updateDataTasks.GetOrAdd(viewModels, modelProvider.GetTimeSeriesDataFor(viewModels.KPIViewModel.KPIModel,
                                                                                    TimeSpanViewModel.StartTime,
                                                                                    TimeSpanViewModel.EndTime));
            }
        }
        await Task.WhenAll(updateDataTasks.Values);

        foreach (KeyValuePair<ITimeSeriesDataViewModel, Task<ITimeSeriesDataModel>> item in updateDataTasks)
        {
            item.Key.TimeSeriesDataModel = item.Value.Result;
        }
```

The problem is the lock can't contain an await, so get the data before awaiting?